# What are the criteria for bad answers?

Tags: discussion

I came across a [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/145075/how-long-is-a-mission-available/252155#252155) that is regarding a concrete subject, requesting to know the duration of the deadline of a feature in a game.

The only answer was vague, inconclusive, and not actually true. I'll focus on them by **bolding** incorrect statements, and emphatise statements that while are true, they're not actually being helpful (they're essentially "yes, that happens, but you already knew that. I don't know when it happens either").

> if the mission isn't a council mission or otherwise important for the story to continue, there is *definitely* a deadline. For instance, if you detect a UFO but don't have any suitable fighters to engage, *after the day goes by the UFO escapes and might come back and shoot down a satellite.*
>
> Basically, **you can't wait past midnight of the same day** you get the mission **or else it will disappear**.
>
> Gangplank and the other missions that expansion pack can be put off indefinitely and they will come back in about 2 weeks.

The answer has two downvotes, and is, at least in my opinion a bad answer as it's not only not really answering the question, but also flat out wrong in some aspects. However, despite being flagged by me, a moderator disagrees and declined my flag.

When/why should bad answers be voted, and what constitutes a bad answer?

Comment: What are you flagging it as? That's important, as you seem to be more asking about a flag issue. If you flagged as NAA, that's not what it's for - the decline reason clearly states NAA is not to be used for something that is technically incorrect or an altogether wrong answer.

Comment: Does it attempt to answer the question? Then NAA doesn't apply. Even if it's wrong. That's what downvotes are for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the flag, and I was the moderator that declined it, so I will speak as to why.

It was flagged as very low quality - I declined it because it's not a low quality answer, it's just wrong. Think of low quality as more in regards to the actual format/structure of the answer - the more it looks like your cat walked across the keyboard, the more it is VLQ.

See [this MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122443/what-does-the-very-low-quality-flag-mean-in-regards-to-answers) for more guidance. In general, flagging answers because they're wrong is not the way to go. That's where you should be using your downvote and commenting powers.

Comment: Thank you for the anwser, however, in that case the flag description is somewhat misleading : "This answer has severe (...) content problems."

Comment: Just cause you're a mod on Pets doesn't mean you can throw cats in your answer. XD

Comment: @Daedric Cats go where they want to, I can't control that! :P

Comment: Also, there was a Lifehacks.SE questions related to cats walking on keyboards